# Six-sided and four-sided dice question contradiction

Tags: probability, dice

Suppose we have two fair dice, with six sides (numbered 1 to 6) and with four sides (numbered 1 to 4). Suppose we pick a die at random and throw it, the result is announced to be 2 and the die is discarded. Then we pick the remaining die and throw it. What is the expectation of the second throw?

On the one hand, us getting 2 on the first throw, does not provide us with information on whether the first die was six-sided or four-sided, so we could argue that by total expectation the expectation of the second throw is just the average of expectations:
$$
E(X)=(3.5)\frac{1}{2} + (2.5)\frac{1}{2}=3
$$

On the other hand, we know that we got 2 on the first throw, so the expectation of the second throw is:
$$
E(X)=(1)\frac{2}{9} + (2)\frac{1}{9} + (3)\frac{2}{9} + (4)\frac{2}{9} + (5)\frac{1}{9} + (6)\frac{1}{9}=3.22
$$
It seems to me that there is a contradiction?

Comment: the first toss does give you some information about the second.  Since you got a $2$, which could have come from either die, that increases your perceived probability that you got the four sided die, you need to take that into account.

Comment: "*Us getting 2 on the first throw, does not provide us with information on whether the first dice was six-sided or four-sided*"  Why do you say that?  It certainly does make us more inclined to believe the first die was the four-sided

Comment: Compare to the problem of a billion-sided die and a two-sided die (*ignoring the physical limitations of such things*).  We pick a die at random and throw it and it comes up a $2$.  "*does not provide us information...*"  I'd wager a huge sum of money that the $2$ came from the two-sided die... not the billion-sided die, and would be correct most of the time.

Comment: Imagine that instead of a 6-sided die and a 4-sided die, you have a 1000-sided die and a 4-sided die. You pick one of the two dice uniformly at random, then roll it: it's a 2. Doesn't this give you a huuuge hint that you probably picked the 4-sided die first?

Comment: As for your calculation of $E(X)$... what is going on there?  What are these $\frac{2}{9}$'s and $\frac{1}{9}$'s representing?  First, find out the probability the $2$ actually came from the four-sided die using Bayes' theorem.  Then find the probability that the second die shows a $1$ which relies on that information to have calculated.

Comment: But we have already selected dice at random, so the chance of us selecting 6-dice is the same as 4-dice, no?

Comment: Before anything was said and done... we picked a die at random, yes.  Then we rolled the die and we saw a $2$.  *Given this information* we are more inclined to believe it is a four sided die we were holding to begin with and so this influences our beliefs about what number it is we are about to roll in the second roll.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> On the one hand, us getting 2 on the first throw, does not provide us with information on whether the first dice was six-sided or four-sided

This sentence is false.

Imagine that instead of a 6-sided die and a 4-sided die, you had a 1000000-sided die, numbered 1-1000000, and a 4-sided die, numbered 1-4. You select one of the two dice uniformly at random, and roll it, and the result is a 2. Do you really claim that you have no information about which die was selected? Intuitively, it is very probable that the 4-sided die was selected; if the 1000000-sided die had been selected, the result could have been anything between 1 and 1000000, and it would look like quite an unprobable coincidence that the result was a 2.

A great tool to formalise this intuition and turn it into precise numbers, and make it work with a 6-sided die instead of a 1000000-sided die, is Bayes' theorem.

Let $D_6$ be the event "we picked the 6-sided die first" and $D_4$ the event "we picked the 4-sided die first". Let $R_2$ be the event "we rolled a 2 on the first roll". Then, in the absence of information, the probability of picking the 6-sided die first is $P(D_6) = \frac{1}{2}$; but the probability of having picked the 6-sided die, knowing that we rolled a 2, is noted $P(D_6 \,|\, R_2)$ and can be calculated using Bayes' theorem:

\begin{align*}
P(D_6 \,|\, R_2) & = \frac{P(R_2 \,|\, D_6)P(D_6)}{P(R_2)} \\
P(D_6 \,|\, R_2) & = \frac{P(R_2 \,|\, D_6)P(D_6)}{P(R_2 \,|\, D_6)P(D_6) + P(R_2 \,|\, D_4)P(D_4)} \\
\end{align*}

Filling in these values:

- $P(D_6) = P(D_4) = \frac{1}{2}$;
- $P(R_2 \,|\, D_6) = \frac{1}{6}$;
- $P(R_2 \,|\, D_4) = \frac{1}{4}$.

We get:
\begin{align*}
P(D_6 \,|\, R_2) & = \frac{\frac{1}{6}\times\frac{1}{2}}{\frac{1}{6}\times\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4}\times\frac{1}{2}} \\
P(D_6 \,|\, R_2) & = \frac{2}{5} \\
\end{align*}
Thus, after observing that we rolled a 2, the probability that we picked the 6-sided die is $\frac{2}{5}$, and the probability that we picked the 4-sided die is $\frac{3}{5}$.

(If we had used a 1000000-sided die and a 4-sided die, using the same reasoning we would have found that after observing a 2, the probability of having picked the 1000000-sided die is only $\frac{1}{250001}$, or $0.0004\%$.)

Now you can calculate the expectation of the second roll after having observed a 2 on the first roll. Calling $X$ the random variable equal to the result of the second roll:

\begin{align*}
\mathbb{E}(X \,|\, R_2) & = \mathbb{E}(X \,|\, D_6)P(D_6 \,|\, R_2) + \mathbb{E}(X \,|\, D_4)P(D_4 \,|\, R_2) \\
\mathbb{E}(X \,|\, R_2) & = 2.5 \times \frac{2}{5} + 3.5 \times \frac{3}{5} \\
\mathbb{E}(X \,|\, R_2) & = 3.1 \\
\end{align*}

**Thus the expectation of the second roll, having observed a 2 on the first roll, is 3.1.** This is slightly higher than the expectation of the second roll we would have calculated if we hadn't observed the first roll: $$\mathbb{E}(X) = \mathbb{E}(X \,|\, D_6)P(D_6) + \mathbb{E}(X \,|\, D_4)P(D_4) = 2.5 \times \frac{1}{2} + 3.5 \times \frac{1}{2} = 3$$

Comment: I think your calculation of $P(D_6 | R_2)$ and $P(D_4 | R_2)$ is correct but you mistakenly flipped them when calculating $E(X| R_2)$. I believe the result should have been $2.9$. This is actually slightly _lower_ than the expectation value ignoring the first roll result - as it should be because the observation makes us a bit more confident we picked the die with the smaller number of sides.

Comment: @aekmr D6 is the event of picking a six-sided die first, in which case the remaining die will be four-sided with the expectation 2.5, right?

Comment: @aekmr I didn't flip them, but I agree that my choice of notation, in hindsight, was rather poor. $D_6$ is the event "the six-sided die was chosen for the first roll", which is equal to the event "the 4-sided die was chosen for the second roll". Instead of naming the events, I should have given names to two random variables $F_1$ and $F_2$ noting the number of faces of each roll, and refer to this event as $(F_1 = 6)$ or equivalently $(F_2 = 4)$.

Comment: I might just edit my post and use these notations instead.

Comment: @aekmr I confirm that $E(X \,|\, R_2)$ is 3.1 and not 2.9, and it is *higher* than $E(X)$, because if we observe a 2 on the first roll, then we're a bit more confident that we picked the small die on the first roll, which means we're a bit more confident that we picked the big die on the second roll.

Comment: Apologies for the confusion - I somehow managed to miss that we're discarding the originally picked die (I shouldn't comment late at night :)). Instead, I assumed the opposite - that we're re-using the same one for the second roll. Your $3.1$ result is of course correct.

Answer (score 2):

Let $A$ represent the event we rolled the four-sided die in the first throw.  Then $A^c$ represents the event we rolled a six-sided die in the first throw.  Remember the second throw we are rolling the other die.

Let $B$ represent the event the outcome of the first roll is a $2$.

We are told $\Pr(A)=\Pr(A^c)=\frac{1}{2}$.  We are told by the fact the dice are fair that $\Pr(B\mid A)=\frac{1}{4}$ and $\Pr(B\mid A^c)=\frac{1}{6}$.

Let $X$ be the random variable representing the outcome of the second die throw.

We are tasked with calculating $E[X\mid B]$.

For this, we look at $1\cdot \Pr(X=1\mid B)+2\cdot \Pr(X=2\mid B)+\dots+6\cdot \Pr(X=6\mid B)$

Let us examine $\Pr(X=1\mid B)$ more closely.  We have $\Pr(X=1\mid B) = \dfrac{\Pr(X=1\cap B)}{\Pr(B)} = \dfrac{\Pr(X=1\cap A\cap B)+\Pr(X=1\cap A^c\cap B)}{\Pr(B\cap A)+\Pr(B\cap A^c)}$

$=\dfrac{\Pr(A)\Pr(X=1\cap B\mid A)+\Pr(A^c)\Pr(X=1\cap B\mid A^c)}{\Pr(A)\Pr(B\mid A)+\Pr(A^c)\Pr(B\mid A^c)}=\dfrac{\Pr(A)\Pr(B\mid A)\Pr(X=1\mid B\cap A)+\Pr(A^c)\Pr(B\mid A^c)\Pr(X=1\mid B\cap A^c)}{\Pr(A)\Pr(B\mid A)+\Pr(A^c)\Pr(B\mid A^c)}$

Recognize that $\Pr(X=1\mid A\cap B) = \Pr(X=1\mid A)$.  Now... these we can actually find from the problem statement.

$=\dfrac{\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{4}\cdot\frac{1}{6}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{6}\cdot\frac{1}{4}}{\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{6}} =\dfrac{1}{5}$

Similarly we calculate for $X=2, X=3, X=4$.  In the case of $X=5$ note that $\Pr(X=5\mid A^c)=0$ and not $\frac{1}{6}$ since there does not exist a face numbered $5$ on the four-sided die.  That yields an answer of $\frac{1}{10}$ for those.

This gives a final calculation of our expectation as being:

$$1\cdot \frac{1}{5}+2\cdot \frac{1}{5}+3\cdot\frac{1}{5}+4\cdot\frac{1}{5}+5\cdot\frac{1}{10}+6\cdot\frac{1}{10}=3.1$$

---

Note, a priori I would not have expected each face of the two dice to be equally likely results of the second throw given a particular result of the first throw and so would have rejected an answer that attempts to assume that fact.  This analysis does show that this happens to be the case here.  Remember that this is the exception, not the norm.  Be very careful about trying to use $\Pr(A)=\frac{|A|}{|S|}$ as this is many times blatantly incorrect to do.  There are two outcomes to a lottery, you win or you lose.  You don't win with probability $\frac{1}{2}$ however.

Comment: *"Remember that this is the exception, not the norm."*  What do you mean by that?

Comment: @Stef for instance, consider the problem of just looking at the expectation of the first throw having not conditioned it on anything.  There are ten different faces that could show up.  These ten faces are not equally likely however.  The sole face labeled $6$ appears with probability $\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1}{6}=\frac{1}{12}$, not with probability $\frac{1}{10}$

Comment: I agree with the comment you just posted, but I still have no idea what you meant with "Remember that this is the exception, not the norm."