# Law of total conditional expectation question

Tags: probability, expected-value, conditional-expectation, dice

I was looking at the accepted answer of this post : [Six-sided and four-sided dice question contradiction](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4532753/six-sided-and-four-sided-dice-question-contradiction). It says :

$\mathbb{E}(X \,|\, R_2)  = \mathbb{E}(X \,|\, D_6)P(D_6 \,|\, R_2) + \mathbb{E}(X \,|\, D_4)P(D_4 \,|\, R_2)$ where $D_4$ and $D_6$ are disjoint events forming a partition.

I thought however that the right formula was $\mathbb{E}(X \,|\, R_2)  = \mathbb{E}(X \,|\, D_6 \cap R_2)P(D_6 \,|\, R_2) + \mathbb{E}(X \,|\, D_4 \cap R_2)P(D_4 \,|\, R_2) $.

Also, I see no reason why $D_6 \cap R_2=D_6$ could hold. Is there something I misunderstand here because the post gets the right answer in the end so it's a bit weird to me.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, $X$ and $R_2$ are [conditionally independent](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conditional_independence) given $D_6$ -- both formulas give the same result. Knowing the first die rolled a 2 is evidence whether it was a d4 or d6, but once it is known that the d6 was rolled first, the fact that it rolled a 2 does not affect the subsequent roll of the d4.

If e.g. there was an additional rule that the second die counts as zero if it matches the first die, then $X$ and $R_2$ would not be conditionally independent and only your formula would be correct.

Answer (score 0):

> I thought however that the right formula was $\mathbb{E}(X \,|\, R_2)  = \mathbb{E}(X \,|\, D_6 \cap R_2)P(D_6 \,|\, R_2) + \mathbb{E}(X \,|\, D_4 \cap R_2)P(D_4 \,|\, R_2) $.

Lacking formal training, my personal attack on such probability problems relies heavily on having developed intuition.  So, I can offer an intuitive explanation (only) why the formula excerpted at the start of this response is wrong.

Dissect, for example, the expression

$$\mathbb{E}(X \,|\, D_6 \cap R_2) \times P(D_6 \,|\, R_2) \tag1 $$

The right hand factor in (1) above, $~\displaystyle P(D_6 \,|\, R_2)~$ *captures* the fact that $~P(D_6)~$ is being computed under the **assumption** that $~R_2~$ has occurred.  Now, the left hand factor in (1) above should be computing the expected factor of the 2nd throw, under the assumption that the die in question is 6 sided.

Instead, you are attempting to **re-use** the fact that the *first throw* was a 2 in computing the expected value of the second throw, when the die is 6 sided.

In effect, you are attempting to use fact that the first throw was a 2 **twice**, which is inappropriate.

---

I emphasize, this is an *informal* intuitive response, designed to allow you to develop a feel for the right formula, rather than having you memorize the formula for a given problem.

The (intuitive) general formula is that if you have two possibilities, Possibility-1 and Possibility-2, then your
expectation is

$$[\text{probability of Possibility-1} \times \text{expectation of Possibility-1}] \\+ [\text{probability of Possibility-2} \times \text{expectation of Possibility-2}]. \tag2 $$

So, examining (2) above, you have to ask yourself, is Possibility-1 represented by the die being 6 sided, or is it represented by the die being 6 sided and having a 2 appear on the first throw?

This is a tricky question.  My perspective is that the fact that a 2 occurred on the first roll is **already being used** to compute the probability of Possibility-1.  Therefore, the fact that the 2 occurred on the first roll should not be used *a second time.*